# Password encryption of jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, encryption

I want to store my own credentials(for a plugin) in credentials.xml in Jenkins through Java Code.Password field in Jenkins is as below.
  {AQAAABAAAAAQh5r9UePk51PcI24Ev+LAtF5jJh47qZQV88suSF/xF/U=}
What is the algorithm Jenkins is using to implement encryption?And also any JAVA code to store credentials.

When I researched on this, it was said that Jenkins uses aes 128 ecb encryption.Please confirm this and how hudson.util.Secret file can be read in Java.